# How to get AVFoundation devices to have a consistent playback rate (1.0x) W/ FFMPEG on MacOS

Tags: macos, mac, ffmpeg, video-encoding, recording

Some background: I've been recording my "camera" with QuickTime, but it only allows for two quality options, low quality (720p60fps), or high quality (1080p60fps encoded with ProRes422), as you can see, there's really no control here. You either get underwhelming results, or overkill.
Reasons for another program/FFMPEG:

1. Split recordings up into segments (ie every hour, start a new recording)
2. A safer container, as I've had multiple corrupted files with QT. (mkv)
3. Control over the bitrate.
4. Handle multiple cameras/angles at once. (Opening instances of QuickTime gets messy & tiring real fast.)

What I'm trying to accomplish, is a 1080p 60FPS capture of my Elgato HD60s+ (appears as a camera to MacOS), with FFMPEG. I just want to capture the video (As I have audio being recorded elsewhere, due to FFMPEG having audio issues on Mac, that I tried to solve for 8+ hours, to no avail.)

To start, this is the following output for:

> ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""

```
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] AVFoundation video devices:
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [0] Reincubate Camo
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [1] HD Pro Webcam C920
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [2] Game Capture HD60 S+
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [3] Capture screen 0
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] AVFoundation audio devices:
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [0] Wavelink test
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [1] Elgato Wave:3
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [2] Krisp Mk2
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [3] Reincubate
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [4] Safari
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [5] Astro MixAmp Pro Voice
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [6] Wave Link Stream
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [7] Game Capture HD60 S+
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [8] Elgato Audio
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [9] krisp microphone
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [10] CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Audio
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [11] StreamOutput
>     [AVFoundation indev @ 0x14c638710] [12] HD Pro Webcam C920
>     : Input/output error
```

The basic command that I've been using is: `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "2:none" output.mkv`, which throws an error:

> 

```
>     [avfoundation @ 0x159008200] Selected framerate (29.970030) is not supported by the device.
>     [avfoundation @ 0x159008200] Supported modes:
>     [avfoundation @ 0x159008200] 1920x1080@[59.940180 59.940180]fps
```

So using this command gets us workable footage. `ffmpeg -framerate 59.940180 -f avfoundation -i "2:none" output.mkv`, but it produces a video that falls out of sync. After 1 minute it's ~3 seconds ahead (1.03x)

This is the log from the following output video

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
[avfoundation @ 0x12d00ca00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, avfoundation, from '2:none':
  Duration: N/A, start: 991066.674467, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 1920x1080, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
File 'output.mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] MB rate (8160000000) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] profile High 4:2:2, level 6.2, 4:2:2, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] 264 - core 161 r3048 b86ae3c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv422p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 1000k fps, 1k tbn, 1000k tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 9219 fps= 55 q=-1.0 Lsize=   49384kB time=00:02:42.68 bitrate=2486.8kbits/s speed=0.973x    
video:49319kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.133110%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] frame I:47    Avg QP:21.49  size:121163
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] frame P:2720  Avg QP:23.86  size: 12078
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] frame B:6452  Avg QP:26.29  size:  1853
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] consecutive B-frames:  5.1%  4.0%  2.2% 88.7%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] mb I  I16..4: 15.2% 68.0% 16.7%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  1.5%  0.2%  P16..4: 28.0%  4.1%  4.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:61.1%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 25.5%  0.2%  0.0%  direct: 0.1%  skip:73.9%  L0:40.0% L1:59.6% BI: 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] 8x8 transform intra:64.8% inter:81.0%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 50.1% 43.2% 8.9% inter: 3.1% 3.8% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26% 32%  5% 37%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 23% 21%  4%  6%  6%  7%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 28% 11%  5%  7%  6%  8%  4%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 62% 17% 18%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.1% UV:2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] ref P L0: 59.6% 14.8% 17.1%  8.5%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] ref B L0: 93.8%  4.6%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] ref B L1: 96.3%  3.7%
[libx264 @ 0x12c016c00] kb/s:2482.67
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

**I want to make it very clear that I have searched & searched, tried many, upon many different commands & couldn't fix the issue with the video not playing at a consistent 1.0x speed.**

Upon all of this, I've tried vsync, encoding presets -ultrafast, capturing the raw footage, it doesn't matter what I seem to do, I can't get the video to just work.

if you made it this far, **THANK YOU!** If you need any clarification, I'll check this multiple times a day, so you should expect a reply within ~12 hours!

Comment: How do you know the video is out of sync and not the audio instead? What are the audio issues with ffmpeg?

Comment: The audio records for a few seconds, then cuts out, then comes back, repeatedly. see the following FFMPEG ticket for more info: (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4513)

As for the video de-syncing, I record a 10 minute video with a timer being displayed on the input. When looking at the video, the timer starts at 10 minutes, & at about 9M 30S in, the "10 minutes" have passed. So it's playing back at 1.03x. 

Another thing to note: It's picking up 58.11FPS when inspecting the footage. It "should" be 60/59.94FPS.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with this issue as well. It seems to be due to the stitching together of frames, meaning that dropped frames would give you a shorter video at the same rate (i.e. a faster video). I've found a solution that allows for a stable frame rate:

### -framerate and -r are separate input options

If you take a look at [this documentation page](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) it explains that `-r` and `-framerate` are separate options, but generally you will want to use the input option `-framerate`.

`-r` as an input option works differently than `-r` as an output option. My understanding is that using `-framerate` as an input option tells the webcam capturing the footage what settings to use for the input stream *but doesn't account for frame dropping or extra frames on the output stream.*

### Specifying the framerate of the output file

Instead, as mentioned in [this wiki page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate), you can use the `-r` option *as an output option* to specify a constant frame rate stream if using `.mp4` as your target format. However since you're using `.mkv` it will specify a FPS ceiling and allow lower FPS than the maximum specified.

Because your input is recording at roughly 60fps, then the following command would drop every other frame to give you a stable 30fps:

`ffmpeg -framerate 59.940180 -f avfoundation -i "2:none" -r 30 output.mkv`

Since you're actually looking to record at 60 frames per second, then raising the fps ceiling doesn't do much for you when writing to `.mkv`. Instead, another option would be to use an FPS filter that will duplicate frames if needed to reach the 60 fps you're looking for. An example command would be:

`ffmpeg -framerate 59.940180 -f avfoundation -i "2:none" -filter:v fps=60 output.mkv`

This would drop any frames above 30fps and duplicate any frames below that number to give you a stable framerate and (hopefully) a stable recording speed.

#### Extra Note

Something else that may not be important to your needs, but is worth considering is that the default functionality of your above command will also handle encoding your input stream before saving it to disk. **This is highly CPU intensive for higher-end cameras, or for multi-cam setups.** This could be part of the problem you are experiencing, unless you have a very beefy computer.

A solution here (which is what I currently do) is to copy the video stream to file without encoding, and then performing the encoding later. i.e.

`ffmpeg -framerate 59.940180 -f avfoundation -i "2:none" -c:v copy -filter:v fps=60 output.mkv`

The above command changes the video codec to just copy the stream instead of using an encoding algo. `-c:v copy` does this.

Then you can later encode the output with something like:

`ffmpeg -i out.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset medium -tune film -pix_fmt yuv420p encoded.mkv`

Notice that `-c:v` now specifies `libx264`. Hope this helps!